# BuddyPress "Order By" function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, wordpress, buddypress, members

I am using WP 3.5.1 and BP 1.7.2. The "Order by" function in my website :

http://teachersinvietnam.com/members/

isn't working. In Chrome I have the following message :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined
>   global.js:658

What can I do to fix this problem ?

Thank you very much,

Regards, Vincent

Answer (score 0):

That's the problem with the theme files.
The theme was created for BuddyPress 1.5 or 1.6 (and was not updated for 7 months).
But as I can see [here](http://teachersinvietnam.com/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/readme.txt) you are using the latest BP 1.7.2.

You need to contact theme author [here in the forum](http://wordpress.org/tags/frisco-for-buddypress) or create a ticket [here on Github](https://github.com/davidtcarson/frisco/issues).